# Tandem relay that connects the (4-20mA) actuator outputs of two identical speed controllers to two diesel engines

Tags: resistors, relay

I have a tandem relay that connects the (4-20 mA) actuator outputs of two identical speed controllers to two diesel engines. I was wondering if you could explain to me how the tandem relay works.

The relay is made using resistors, diodes, and a relay. I am including a picture of the relay.

[image: Tandem relay]

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Please explain where the image came from and provide a link.

Comment: the parts list shows 6 relays ... where are they?